# How to insert new entity when one property was created by id of entity ? (id means identity number)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Look at example:

I have a table `user` in my database. I use Entity Framework to work with the database, so I have a class `user` as an entity which has a `id` column was set as `identity` in the database.

Now, I insert a new user to database:

```
 UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(new MyDataContext());
 unitOfWork.UserRepository.Insert(new user {
                                               name = 'something here',
                                               userToken = id + "randomstring here"
                                           });
 unitOfWork.Save();
```

After many hours, I have tried in many ways. The `userToken` is always = 0 + 'randomstring here'.

Please let me know how to get the expected value of `userToken`.

Comment: what is id here?

Comment: id is an AUTO INCREMENT column in table, (primary key)

Comment: Since the `identity` value is **only** defined once the row **has been inserted**, you cannot do it like this. You *could* have an `AFTER INSERT` trigger on the SQL Server table that would handle this - or you need to load the entity after the initial insert and then set the `userToken` value and save again

Comment: @marc_s exactly.

Comment: @marc_s, I'm clearly now! It can be the best answer. Kindly thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can get Id only when changes will saved. So, you need add your entity, save it, update your entity and save it again. It happens because database generate Id when row inserts.

Also you can add your entity, get ID, rollback it and add again with knowing Id

Comment: If you roll back and insert again, nothing guarantees you that you will get the same identity in the second insert. perhaps some other request made an insert between the two inserts, and used the id from the first insert.

Comment: @TsahiAsher sure. Only if somebody will add new user in the same time :)

Comment: Which is quite likely in any production web site.